# Got an error in `php artisan migrate` in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, host

I always use Laravel project since Laravel 4 up to 7. But this is my first time encountering and error when I migrate my database in freshly download Laravel. This is the error when I migrate:

```
        $e = $event->getThrowable();

        if (!$event->hasResponse()) {
            $this->finishRequest($request, $type);

            throw $e;
        }

        $response = $event->getResponse();

        // the developer asked for a specific status code
        if (!$event->isAllowingCustomResponseCode() && !$response->isClientError() && !$response->isServerError() && !$response->isRedirect()) {
            // ensure that we actually have an error response
            if ($e instanceof HttpExceptionInterface) {
                // keep the HTTP status code and headers
                $response->setStatusCode($e->getStatusCode());
                $response->headers->add($e->getHeaders());
            } else {
                $response->setStatusCode(500);
            }
        }

        try {
            return $this->filterResponse($response, $request, $type);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $response;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a human-readable string for the specified variable.
     */
    private function varToString($var): string
    {
        if (\is_object($var)) {
            return sprintf('an object of type %s', \get_class($var));
        }

        if (\is_array($var)) {
            $a = [];
            foreach ($var as $k => $v) {
                $a[] = sprintf('%s => ...', $k);
            }

            return sprintf('an array ([%s])', mb_substr(implode(', ', $a), 0, 255));
        }

        if (\is_resource($var)) {
            return sprintf('a resource (%s)', get_resource_type($var));
        }

        if (null === $var) {
            return 'null';
        }

        if (false === $var) {
            return 'a boolean value (false)';
        }

        if (true === $var) {
            return 'a boolean value (true)';
        }

        if (\is_string($var)) {
            return sprintf('a string ("%s%s")', mb_substr($var, 0, 255), mb_strlen($var) > 255 ? '...' : '');
        }

        if (is_numeric($var)) {
            return sprintf('a number (%s)', (string) $var);
        }

        return (string) $var;
    }
}
```

Error

```
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Supporting Enterprises\Projects\Laravel Projects\SuperpagesAPI\artisan(18): require()
#1 {main}
  thrown in D:\Supporting Enterprises\Projects\Laravel Projects\SuperpagesAPI\vendor\autoload.php on line 7

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ComposerAutoloaderInitbe984857c53a573c5f216d0eb36fe0e7' not found in D:\Supporting Enterprises\Projects\Laravel Projects\SuperpagesAPI\vendor\autoload.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Supporting Enterprises\Projects\Laravel Projects\SuperpagesAPI\artisan(18): require()
#1 {main}
  thrown in D:\Supporting Enterprises\Projects\Laravel Projects\SuperpagesAPI\vendor\autoload.php on line 7
```

Before this happen I start IIS from the IIS Manager. I don't know if this will effect. I turn it on because I run a C# web application on my end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is composer problem. Just try to run this bash script:

```
composer dump-autoload
```